# Proof linear independence of column vectors of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Have a system of linear equation in matrix form:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_0 &  a_1& a_2\\ 
 a_1&  a_0& a_1\\ 
 a_2& a_1 & a_0 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2\\ 
x_3
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which has solution, moreover $x_1\ne0$. Proof that column vectors of the matrix are linear independent.

I feel completely stuck. I don't even know where to start. I know about linear combinations, linear spans, signs of linear dependence/independence, but I don't understand how to use them.

Comment: Do you know how to show linear independency or where are stuck? What is your definition of linear independence?

Comment: There might only be a solution if the matrix is invertible. Its not invertible if the columns are  linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0):

So i came with the following idea:
We know that the system $Ax=b$ has at least one solution $\implies$ b is in the span of column vectors of matrix $A$ (lets name those vectors $A_1, A_2, A_3$). We can show linear independence of $b, A_2, A_3$, which will mean that $A_1, A_2, A_3$ are independent too.

Let's suppose that $A_3$ is linear combination of $b,A_2$:
$$\ 
\alpha b+ \beta A_2 = A_3 \
$$
$$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
\alpha + \beta a_1& =& a_2 \\ 
 \beta a_0 &=& a_1\\ 
  \beta a_1 &=& a_0
\end{matrix}\right.
\
$$

From last two: $ \beta^2 a_1 = a_1$. Let's check that $a_1 \ne 0$. Suppose $a_1 = 0$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 &  0& a_2\\ 
 0&  0& 0\\ 
 a_2& 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2\\ 
x_3
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This system can have a solution only if $ x_1 = 0 $, which contradicts the initial condition $x_1 \ne 0$.
Now let's divide $ \beta^2 a_1 = a_1$ by $ a_1$. We get $\beta = \pm 1$.

If $\beta = 1$, than $a_0 = a_1$:
$$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
x_1 + x_2 + \frac{a_2}{a_0}x_3& =& \frac{1}{a_0} \\ 
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 &=& 0 \\ 
\frac{a_2}{a_0}x_1 + x_2 + x_3&=& 0
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
Substracting last two:

$$
(\frac{a_2}{a_0}-1)x_1=0
$$

$x_1 \ne 0$ than $\frac{a_2}{a_0} = 1$

Substituting into the first equation:

$x_1 + x_2 +x_3= \frac{1}{a_0} $  which contradicts second equation.

The same is true if $\beta=-1$.

It shows that we can't express $A_3$ as linear combination of $b, A_2$. Which means that $ A_3, A_2, b$ are linear independent. Therefore, column vectors of the matrix $A$: $A_1, A_2, A_3$ are linear independent.